# Is it possible to link a variable to the data-options of the library of livicons directly with angular?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add the library of livicons to my project, but I would like the value of the name in the data-options of the livicon, to be linked to a value that I get from a JSON, but it generates me an error. I'm working on angular. This is my code:

```html
<i class="livicon-evo" style="cursor: pointer;"
    data-options="name: {{myjson.campoicon}}; size: 30px; style: original; 
                  tryToSharpen: true">
</i>
```

Error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>
> ```
> Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'i'. ("}</i>-->
>
>    <i class="livicon-evo" style="cursor: pointer;"
>        [ERROR ->]data-options="name: {{child.icon}}; size: 30px; 
>                style: original; tryToSharpen: true"></i>
> ```

Comment: Have you tried binding to a string literal as the value of `data-options`? (i.e. `data-options="'name: ' + myjson.campoicon + '; ...'"`) What you've currently as the attribute value isn't a valid literal or variable binding, thus AngularJS throws the error.

Comment: Mixing jQuery and AngularJS like this is asking for trouble.

Comment: the error persists even with the literal string.